# Visual Basic - Ball Jumping Game

Tags: visual-studio, vba

I want to make a mini game with a ball jumping, basically the game is simple, there is a ball and the ball needs to jump over some bars that are closing. I have done the code for the jump.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick() Handles Timer1.Tick

Static intOldTop As Integer
Static intCounter As Integer
Dim intStep As Integer = 10

If intCounter = 0 Then intOldTop = PictureBox1.Top

intCounter += 1

Select Case intCounter
    Case 1 To 20
        PictureBox1.Top -= intStep
    Case 20 To 40
        PictureBox1.Top += intStep
    Case Else
        PictureBox1.Top = intOldTop
        intCounter = 0
        Timer1.Dispose()
End Select

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As     System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar() = " " Then
        Timer1.Interval = 10
        Timer1.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

I have no ideea how to make the bars appear/scroll and making the ball interaction with the bars.

Look for Jelly Jump game.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar with ActionScript 3.0 and sounds a lot easier with AS3.0. I think you should give it a try instead of using VB.